# App doesn't work of built API 18 to 19

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

Previously I have built mt app on API 18 and its works fine. But after building on API 19 app crashes in some use cases on my Android 4.1.2 (on 4.4.2 works fine). After building on API 19 apk size became smaller just of support lib size: was approx 800K but became about 300K. May be the reason in Eclipse doesn't includes support lib? Any suggestions? Thanx

Comment: Inspect the logcat when the crash occurs. This might provide you with the answer.

Comment: @NiekHaarman when runnig on my 4.1.2 device eclipse builds full apk of 900K size and it works great, but when use export wizard apk became just 300K

Comment: @Minas sorry, it seems proguard used)

Comment: Is proguard can be the reason of this problem?

Comment: yes, first try to disable proguard, if app works ok, enable it again and start editing proguard config file to make it work with your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to proguard. You can try to disable proguard and if it starts to work ok you can enable it back and start to modify proguard config file to make it work with the app.